# Bash/sed string replace with contents of file (containing newlines)

Tags: bash, sed

Question for the Bash ninjas: I have an XML template file that has some template markers in the form `{{VARIABLE_NAME}}` and want to find/replace all occurences of that marker with the contents of a text file.

So imagine `template.xml` looks something like this:

```
<?xml>
<root>
    <description>
        {{DESCRIPTION}}
    </description>
</root>
```

And I have a text file called `description.txt` that could potentially contain any characters (let's assume it's already xml-safe for simplicity). I want to replace the marker with the contents of the file, supporting newlines and other characters.

Previously I've been doing this in my code like this (which works great for simple strings):

```
sed -i '' -e "s/{{DESCRIPTION}}/$DESCRIPTION/g" template.xml
```

However, if `$DESCRIPTION` contains newlines, sed balks:

```
sed: 1: "s/{{DESCRIPTION}}/Hello w ...": unescaped newline inside substitute pattern
```

Is there a better way to do this, or should I first search/replace all newlines with escaped variants in the `$DESCRIPTION` variable first. And are there any other characters I need to escape, like `/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the answers. Always interested in learning new ways to do things in Bash. I ended up solving it in a different way, however, by escaping the string using Bash's built-in replace notation, which I just discovered (`sed` failed at this for reasons I'm still not quite clear on):

```
DESCRIPTION=`cat description.txt`
DESCRIPTION=${DESCRIPTION//$'\n'/\\$'\n'} # escape newlines
DESCRIPTION=${DESCRIPTION//\//\\\/} # escape slashes
DESCRIPTION=${INPUT//$'&'/\\$'&'amp;} # escape ampersands
# other xml-escaping...
```

...and then using `sed` to actually do the replacement inline in output.xml:

```
cp -f template.xml output.xml
sed -i '' -e "s/{{DESCRIPTION}}/$DESCRIPTION/g" output.xml
```

Since the newlines and slashes are now escaped (am I missing anything??) the sed command accepts the replacement string without complaint and it renders the output file perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a BASH (sh, actually) script to do the replacement:

```
#!/bin/sh
while IFS= read -r line
do
    case "$line" in
        *{{DESCRIPTION}})
            cat "description.txt"
            ;;
        *)
            echo "$line"
            ;;
    esac
done <"template.xml"
```

In the problem statement, "{{DESCRIPTION}}" appears on a line by itself.  If that is not the case in general, some minor changes would be needed to preserved the other data on the line.

Answer (score 1):

use awk:

```
awk -v RS='\0' 'NR==FNR{r=$0;next}{sub(/\{\{DESCRIPTION\}\}/,r)}7' desc temp.xml
```

I think you know how to play with redirection to save the output into a file.

test: in the example, file `f` contains many "special" chars

```
kent$  cat f.xml
<?xml>
<root>
    <description>
        {{DESCRIPTION}}
    </description>
</root>

kent$  cat f
foo
'
"
O"'
/
\



        - 
bar

kent$  awk -v RS='\0' 'NR==FNR{r=$0;next}{sub(/\{\{DESCRIPTION\}\}/,r)}7' f f.xml
<?xml>
<root>
    <description>
        foo
'
"
O"'
/
\



        - 
bar

    </description>
</root>
```

Comment: This is almost working, but for some reason it's only taking the last line of the file and ignoring anything prior to the last line. It might be my fault, I don't know awk.

Comment: @chaiguy is your awk gnu one?

Comment: I'm running Mac OS X 10.9, so probably not.